# In how many ways can the letters of the word PANACEA be arranged so that the three As are NOT all together?

Tags: combinatorics

PANACEA has 7 letters with 3 As.

There are 4! ways to arrange (P, N, C, E) _ P_N_C_E _. Between these letters, there are 5 slots. So, to arrange 3 As in 5 slots is 5P3. We divide it by 3! for the 3 As to avoid duplicates. We have:

$4!\cdot \frac{5P3}{3!} = 240$

This is the correct answer:

`Total arrangement - 3 A's are together = 3 A's are not together`

$\frac{7!}{3!}-5! = 720$

I need someone to clarify why the first method didn't work or did I made a mistake?

Comment: In what you calculated first, none of the A's are together, but the question says that all three can't be together. So you missed the words, with two A's together.

Comment: Thanks, I got it

Answer (score 5):

The mistake in the first method arises from the fact that it doesn't account for the possibility of As being non-contiguous. The calculation
$$4! \cdot \frac{5P3}{3!}$$
only considers cases where each A is placed in a separate slot between the other letters, but it does not consider cases where two As could be together and the third A is separate.

Comment: To build on this: you could take the first method and up the number of ways to put A and AA into the slots in _P_N_C_E_ (times the $4!$ arrangements of P,N,C,E). There are $5*4$ ways to insert A and AA into those slots -- $4!*5*4=480$, and you get $720$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac{7!}{3!}$ part is the usual permutation of 7 letters, where 3 are the same.

The $5!$ is actually $5 \cdot 4!$, where

- the $4!$ part is the possible arrangements of `PNCE`, as you recognized
- and $5$ are the slots you also recognized, just the excluded cases are only the ones where all the `A`-s are together, so `AAAxxxx`, `xAAAxxx`, `xxAAAxx`, `xxxAAAx`, and `xxxxAAA`.

So you do have all the parts, just they have to be put together differently.

Comment: you can see the second part as $5!$ after all if you treat `AAA` as a single letter and ask how many pemutations of the 5 "letters" there are

Comment: or, similarly, ask how many permutations of `PNCEA` there are, and then say in each case the placement of the remaining two `A`s is forced

Answer (score 1):

The first method is correct, just incomplete.

Continuing on the OP's method:

a) All $A$'s are separate

$$ | P | N | C | E | $$

Using the gap and string method, we see we have to permute (P,N,C,E) as OP said.

We can see that for the four letters, there are 5 gaps in which we place our 3 $A$'s. So we need to pick 3 out of 5 gaps and permute the 4 remaining difference letters.

Hence, $\color{blue}{^5C_{3} \times 4!}$

b) 2 A's are together

Let the group $AA$ be represented as $G$.

So, we need to permute (P,N,C,E,G,A)

However, we cannot have $G$ next to an $A$ as then there would be 3 consecutive $A$'s, which is forbidden.

Hence we make  2 cases:

i) G is at either end of the word (2 such cases; when it is at the start and end)

$$G,P,N,C,E,A$$

For the letter directly adjacent G, we cannot have A, meaning we have to pick a letter out of (P,C,E,N) and permute the remaining 3 letters, as well as A.

Hence, $\color{blue}{ ^2C_{1} \times ^4C_{1} \times 4!}$

ii) G is somewhere in the middle of the word (4 such cases)

$$P, G, N, C, A, E$$

Again, we cannot have $A$ adjacent to $G$ and since there are 2 spots for letters adjacent to G, we have to pick 2 letters out of (P,C,E,N), permute those 2 letters adjacent to G; and permute the remaining 2 letters as well as A.

Hence, $\color{blue} {^4C_{1} \times ^4C_{2}  \times 2! \times 3!}$

The net sum is:

$$ ^5C_{3} \times 4! + ^2C_{1} \times ^4C_{1}  \times 2! \times 4! + ^4C_{1} \times ^4C_{2} \times 3!$$

$$= 240 + 192 + 288$$

$$= \color{blue}{720}$$

As for why $\dfrac{7!}{3!} - 5!$ is correct, it's fairly simple.

The total permutations of the letters $PANACEA$ possible is $\dfrac{7!}{3!}$ (as 3 $A$'s repeat, the $3!$ term is added to the denominator) and the permutations where the group $AAA$ is present is 5!

Consider the group $AAA$ to be $G'$, so it's effectively permuting (G',P,C,E,N) which is equal to 5!.

Hope this answer helped.

Comment: Thank you, learned something...